# Add SoapHeader to a Spring WS Endpoint

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I have a spring ws endpoint as part of a Spring Integration project and I would like to access the Soap Header. When I add the SoapHeader to the method parameters i get the following exception:

> [10/05/16 05:00:05:005 PDT] localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG
>   springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.doWith():
>   Method [public
>   com.bstonetech.ptms.integration.model.ws.external.contract.GetContractResponse
>   com.bstonetech.ptms.integration.service.ws.GetContractEndpoint.getContract(com.bstonetech.ptms.integration.model.ws.external.contract.GetContractRequest,org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext)
>   throws java.lang.Exception] is not eligible for Message handling Found
>   more than one parameter type candidate:
>   [@org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload
>   com.bstonetech.ptms.integration.model.ws.external.contract.GetContractRequest]
>   and [org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext]. [10/05/16
>   05:00:05:005 PDT] localhost-startStop-1  WARN
>   web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh(): Exception
>   encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type [class
>   com.bstonetech.ptms.integration.service.ws.GetContractEndpoint] has no
>   eligible methods for handling Messages.

The same error occurs when using MessageContext messageContext too.

I am obviously missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Integration is as follows:

```
   <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="contractMarshaller" context-path="com.bstonetech.ptms.integration.model.ws.external.contract"/>
   <ws:inbound-gateway id="getContractWs" request-channel="inboundGetContractChannel" mapped-request-headers="fileId" mapped-reply-headers="fileId"
                       marshaller="contractMarshaller" unmarshaller="contractMarshaller"/>



   <int:service-activator id="contractEndpoint" input-channel="inboundGetContractChannel" ref="getContractEndpoint"/>
```

The endpoint looks as follows:

```
@Endpoint
public class GetContractEndpoint {

   private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://bstonetech.com/contract";

   @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetContractRequest")
   @ResponsePayload
   public GetContractResponse getContract(@RequestPayload GetContractRequest request, SoapHeader soapHeader) throws Exception {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay. We were busy with Spring Integration [4.3.0.RC1](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/12/spring-integration-4-3-0-release-candidate-available) release :-).

Well, looks like you have missed something and therefore ended up with the mix of concerns.

The Spring WS *POJO method invocation* annotations (`@RequestPayload`, `@PayloadRoot`) and SOAP-specific argument injection is really for the POJO case, when you have `@Endpoint` on the service and rely on the `@EnableWs` or similar Spring WS mechanism.

On the other hand, right, Spring Integration WS module is fully based on the Spring WS project, but it aims to convert everything into Spring Integration Messaging model as fast as possible. Therefore a result of the `<ws:inbound-gateway>` is `Message` sent to the `request-channel="inboundGetContractChannel"`. In your case the `payload` will be already unmarshalled to some your domain object according to the JaxB mapping.

The `<service-activator>` can now deal only with the Messaging infrastructure and it already know nothing about SOAP. That is the general purpose of the Messaging, when you can switch to fully different source (e.g. DB), but still use the same `<service-activator>`.

To meet some *POJO method invocation* there are useful annotations like `@Payload` `@Header` etc.

To be consistent and still provide some SOAP info, the `AbstractWebServiceInboundGateway` consults with the `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` and extract `source.getSoapHeader()` state as a separate `MessageHeaders`. So, you still have access to desired headers from request.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. I am now using a PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping to do the mapping the the gateway and simply implement the end point as a POJO.

Comment: You can still do that and get a gain of messaging downstream. Just move all the '@Endpoint' configuration to the @MessagingGateway level

Comment: Leading on from this I have implemented an EnpointInterceptor to intercept every inbound web service call. I write to a database in each case and log success or fault. I would like to be able to pass the created database table row id to the POJO. I see that MessageContext has properties that I can set. Is it possible t get the MessageContext in the POJO or map the properties to headers before the POJO is executed?

Comment: First of all it is fully different question. From other side you are mixing concerns. Such a logic should not be done in the interceptor. This pattern aims do not impact the target message. And from big height removing it from the flow  should end up with idempotent behavior. reconsider the logic and move that `insert into DB` logic to the target `@Endpoint`. Although you can consider to use `ThreadLocal` to store an `id` and retrieve it from your POJO. And yes: clean the `ThreadLocal` here already.